# Where was the location of the “Band of Brothers” scene with Wild Bill firing at a German Patrol?

Tags: band-of-brothers

I’ve been to most *Band of Brothers* locations but one escapes me.

Shortly after the brothers parachute into Normandy, they come across a German patrol with horses and carts etc. Winter signals everyone to wait for his order before opening fire. Wild Bill Guarnere (?) ignores his order and opens fire on the Germans much to Winter’s annoyance.

Can anyone tell me where I need to start to discover this location?

Comment: A screenshot or clip of the film would improve this question. You can include it with an [edit] :)

Comment: It may not have been a real location, a lot of filming was done on sets built in former aircraft manufacturering facilities in Hatfield about 20 miles north of London in the UK. The large amount of space there enabled them to build entire fake villages and forests that were used in filming.

Comment: Thanks for that but I don’t mean the location of the film set. I mean the actual location in Normandy where the incident took place on DDay. Wild Bill Lost his head (he had just heard that his brother had been killed at Monte Cassino) and couldn’t control himself.

Comment: In which case you might be better off asking this on the History Stack Exchange, as you are asking about real historical events.

Comment: You may also need to change the title - 'where did they film' is confusing if you want the location of the historic event rather than the shoot loc.

Comment: Apologies, my fault entirely. I should have distinguished between film site and historical site.

Answer (score 7):

The location you are referring to is called The Ambush Site.

Quoting from [here](http://normandy2013.blogspot.com/2012/08/band-of-brothers-in-normandy.html) and [here](https://dboothnormandytours.com/index.php/the-full-day-band-of-brothers-tour/)

> The Ambush Site
>
> In the Band of Brothers TV show, a supply convoy of horse drawn German wagons is ambushed by the 101st troopers in a railway trestle. In reality, it happened at a T-junction north-east of Sainte-Mere-Eglise. In the crossfire between the American troopers positioned either side of the road, a handful of US soldiers were accidentally killed - something omitted from the series.

The Ambush Site depicted in The Band of Brothers:

Actual The Ambush Site:

[image]

[image]

[Location on Google Maps.](https://www.google.com/maps/search/D423+Sainte-Mere-Eglise./@49.4153329,-1.2968225,138m/data=!3m1!1e3)

Comment: Rahul, you have made my day! Thank you so much for that. I never thought I would find that actual site but, thanks to you, I have. Apologies over the confusion between filming locations and actual historical locations. I confused people who were trying to help by not distinguishing between the two. But again, Rahul, a very sincere thank you.

Comment: @Tatieash: It's my pleasure. Have a safe journey. **☺**

Comment: @Tatieash If am answer is satisfying to you, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check-mark next to the up- and down arrows for voting.

Answer (score 0):

As this has already been answered, take this as just a partial (so it doesn't get lost in the comments)

This podcast:

- says that the ambush took place but the wagon with horses was added by the writers - originally it was just a column of troops.

> "That was the slight *cinematic license taken*.

> It was just some German soldiers marching, but we all thought it would be a little **more interesting** if we **added the wagon** and gave it a dynamic sense to the scene.

> And then the horses was sort of the brutality of it,"